# How to extract info from TXT using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

```
Student no. - Class no.                                          
123123 - 123123123                                                  
Class date: abc 123                       
Year number: 123124 
Class Period:
May 12, 2020 to Aug 31, 2020
Class address: 
blah blah blah
```

How do I extract these info individually and store it in a variable where users can call it from a text file using node and javascript?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? What is your expected output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, './text.txt'), { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  // split to lines, remove white space
  const result = data.split(/\n/g).map((line) => {
    return line.split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean);
  });
  console.log(result);

  // result content:
  // [
  //   ['Student', 'no.', '-', 'Class', 'no.'],
  //   ['123123', '-', '123123123'],
  //   ['Class', 'date:', 'abc', '123'],
  //   ['Year', 'number:', '123124'],
  //   [],
  //   ['Class', 'Period', 'period:'],
  // ];
});
```